# Localizing Images Android Studio

Tags: android

I have some problem when I trying to follow a tutorial to create a localization app: After I created all the folders and place the flag images, I run the app and expect to see the greeting message and corresponding flag for the locales; here is the problem:

[image: picture_1]

The flag should change to Germany flag. (I set England flag as default)

This is the error message when I click the flag(Yes, the flag is a button.)
[image: picture_2]

This is my res folder structure:
[image: picture_3]

This is my res directory:
[image: image_4]

Textview is working fine, only problem is the flag image won't change with the location. Can somebody show me where the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to mention DPI into the name of your drawable folder after language code. For Ex, **drawable-de-rDE-hdpi**. Otherwise it will not find resources.

Comment: I change the folder name but still not fix the problem.

Comment: which device are you using ??

Comment: try removing rDE from folder name, make it as drawable-de-hdpi. here DPI is your device DPI.